# Java type error with generics in Constructor

Tags: java, generics, constructor, undefined

I have a (probably simple) question regarding genrics in Java. I have the following class:

```
public class ValueCollection<Y> implements Collection<Y>
{
    private Set<Entry<?, Y>> entries;

    public ValueCollection(Set<Entry<?, Y>> entries)
    {
        this.entries = entries;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I call the constructor like this:

```
return new ValueCollection<V>(entries);
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
The constructor ValueCollection<V>(Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>) is undefined
```

If I change my class to this:

```
public class ValueCollection<X, Y> implements Collection<Y>
{
    private Set<Entry<X, Y>> entries;

    public ValueCollection(Set<Entry<X, Y>> entries)
    {
        this.entries = entries;
    }
    ...
}
```

and my constructor call to this:

```
return new ValueCollection<K, V>(this.entries());
```

the compile error goes away. I'm just wondering why this is the case. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if you just call the constructor with `new ValueCollection<V>(entries)` in the first case? Your first class only has one type parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Set<Entry<?, V>>` is either *a set of entries with any key type and value type `V`* or *a set of entries with some specific but unknown key type `K` and value type `V`*. Due to the latter the compiler rejects your original constructor invocation.

A `Set<? extends Entry<?, V>>` is *a set of entries which are entries with any key type and value type `V`*. This is exactly what you want, redefine your constructor parameter type to be `Set<? extends Entry<?, V>>`.

You can assign the parameter to your field using either `this.entries = Collections.unmodifiableSet(entries)` or `this.entries = new HashSet<Entry<?, V>>(entries)`. Both right hand sides produce a `Set<Entry<?, V>>` in a way that convinces the compiler it means *a set of entries with any key type and value type `V`*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I wanted to know. Your explanation makes a lot of sense.